# Illuminate\Database\Query Exception - Could Not Find Driver

Tags: laravel, illuminate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm88c.png)

After transferring our application to the server. The application loaded accordingly. When we tried to login to the app, we received this kind of error. PHP version is 8.2.11 and Laravel 10.29.0. Is there something that we missed during the transfer of the application?

Here is the Code Structure:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;



use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;

use Closure;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;



class RedirectIfAuthenticated

{

    /**

     * Handle an incoming request.

     *

     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next

     */

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string ...$guards): Response

    {

        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;



        foreach ($guards as $guard) {

            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);

            }

        }



        return $next($request);

    }

}
```

Thank you for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't enable PDO extension . In your cpanel select

**SOFTWARE > Select PHP Version**

You see all extensions there , enable these extensions :

**pdo ,mysqlnd , ndmysqli , nd_pdo_mysql**